# how to validating only file type in laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation

i want check only file type in laravel validating,request file is below:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'TaskFile' => "file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf|max:10240"
               ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return[
            "TaskFile.mimes"=>"choose correct type jpg,gif,pdf"
        ];
    }
```

in blade:

```
<input id="TaskFile" type="file" class="myform-control @error('TaskFile') is-invalid @enderror" name="TaskFile">
        @error('TaskFile')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
               <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
```

But it doesn't work correctly and the message doesn't appear when select another type of file.

Comment: check your form `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('your.route') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. dump `$request` and see files come to controller

Comment: does anything change if you make the input "required"?

Comment: I looked at the form again, I have used  laravel collective :{!! Form::open(['route' => 'tasks.store', 'method' => 'POST','files' => true]) !!}